Where are the Java classes BarScale, CategoryTicks and BarOptions.IndexAxis?
I am migrating from PrimeFaces 13 to 14. The migration guide says the new chart component allows raw JSON or XDEV Chart.js Java Model. I copied the Java code for the bar chart example from the PrimeFaces showcase. I added these dependencies to my project:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>14.0.5</version>
    <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>software.xdev</groupId>
    <artifactId>chartjs-java-model</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>

The classes BarScale and CategoryTicks are missing. Also BarOptions.IndexAxis.
I would appreciate any help you can give me in solving this problem.

Source code at current showcase version is indeed wrong. You can find the correct source code at https://quarkus-faces-melloware-8a6a34c1.koyeb.app/ui/chart/bar.xhtml?jfwid=bfa32 (link extracted from https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/12377)

Thank you, I'll download it from there
